# Historical usage of "was"/"were" with "you"

Tags: verbs, grammatical-number, pronouns, verb-agreement

I was reading letters from a surgeon to his wife during the Civil War and noticed he used "was" as opposed to "were" on many occasions. Examples:

> I truly wish you was here with me.

> Was you planning to visit...?

Other than this strange (to me) usage, his language was very formal and correct. Has there been an evolution in the accepted usage of *was/were*?

Answer (score 9):

From *The Cambridge History of the English Language: English in North America*, p. 332,
 by John Algeo, [via Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=ia5tHVtQPn8C&lpg=PA332&dq=When%20thou%2C%20thee%2C%20and%20thine%20dropped%20out%20of%20the%20language&pg=PA332#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> When *thou, thee,* and *thine*
>   dropped out of the language in the
>   early Colonial period on both sides of
>   the Atlantic, speakers felt a need
>   nonetheless to distinguish between
>   singular and plural forms. The
>   earliest attempt was simply to make
>   verb agreement do the work: speakers
>   would say *you was* for the singular
>   and *you were* for the plural.
>   Beginning in the eighteenth century,
>   this sensible solution was met with
>   heavy resistance from purists, and
>   *you was* became heavily stigmatized by the end of the nineteenth century in
>   America (though it has by no means
>   dropped out of colloquial speech in
>   the United States).

Comment: +1, I think [Gollum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gollum) speaks like that.

Comment: Fascinating....

Answer (score -4):

This misuse of *was* for *were* in the subjunctive was and is common. **EDIT:** Some wish that it were not so.

Comment: I don't think the question is about the subjunctive. The second example is quite telling. Looks more like a question about dialectal differences.

Comment: @RegDwight - That the writer is wishing for his wife's company *requires* the subjunctive when he expresses the wish in writing. Maybe the grammar error is dialectical, but the error is still an error.

Comment: @Pete Wilson: But if you are using the conjugation *I was/you was/he was//we were/you were/they were* for the simple past, what conjugation are you supposed to use for the subjunctive?