# How to resolve mixing singular and plural on the same noun

Tags: grammatical-number

Let's look at this sentence.

> China **has** as much claim to North Korea as they **have** over Tibet. That is, if they **do** decide to invade and occupy North Korea.

Question

1. You do agree this passage is grammatically problematic, don't you?
2. If using *they* as pronoun for *China* is somehow an imperative in this passage, how would you resolve this grammatical conflict?

Comment: *“That firm does offer a good retirement plan, even if they don’t have a good vacation policy”* has no more of a “grammatical” problem than the original, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: "*That firm **has** a good a good retirement plan, though they **have** not any good vacation policy.*" You believe such a sentence has no grammatical conflict?

Comment: Nobody said *"though they have not"*. I honestly don't understand what you're seeing here. *China* is singular and *they* is plural; both agree with their verbs correctly and thus no grammatical error can be pretended to exist here. The verbs have different subjects: it is only natural that each should agree with its respective subject, not with a different one governing a wholly different verb.

Comment: Exactly. Deal with the phrase in the question.

Comment: I'm more bothered by the *claim to/over* inconsistency than the choice of pronoun.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with your chosen pronouns. Observe how smoothly it flows once a few corrections have been made:

> **China** has as much claim to North Korea as **it** does over Tibet. That is, if **it** does decide to invade and occupy North Korea.

Why did I choose the pronoun **it?** Quite simply because you said China *has*. You should maintain consistency among your pronouns, so if you use the singular "has", you are treating the noun (China) as a single, collective unit. That is, you're talking about China as the country in general as a single entity.

If you'd prefer to use the plural pronoun **they**, then the change is as simple as replacing "has" with "have" and "China" (singular) with "The Chinese" (plural):

> **The Chinese** have as much claim to North Korea as **they** do over Tibet. That is, if **they** do decide to invade and occupy North Korea.

Comment: China is a *they* surely, not an *it*. We're talking about a bunch of people, not a rock.

Comment: Actually, we're talking about a country, or a country's government. Both _its_.

Comment: @tchrist I get your interpretation, but I disagree. Take, for example, the following: "America is a great nation. *It* is the land of the free." You can certainly use "it" when referring to a country if your intention, as vanderpn notes, is to refer to the country itself or the country's government.

Answer (score 1):

> China **has** as much claim to North Korea as they **have** over Tibet.

I don't actually agree that the use of verbs with different number agreement to describe the same logical entity in this sentence is a problem in terms of grammar. (Some people might object to it as a matter of style.) It's usual for verbs to agree with their *immediate* subjects, not necessarily the antecedent to their subjects, and just because an expression refers back to a preceding noun phrase doesn't mean it has to match in the agreement categories of number and person.

Compare:

> Your Highness **is** as generous as you **are** eloquent.

"[The Merchant's Talisman](https://books.google.com/books?id=mW0EAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA171&dq=%22your%20highness%20is%20as%22%20%22as%20you%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwio0Luo5rHTAhUK_IMKHV6lDf0Q6AEIMDAC#v=onepage&q=%22your%20highness%20is%20as%22%20%22as%20you%22&f=false)", by Paul de Musset (in French), translated by G.J. Knox, *The Literary aspirant magazine* (Jan 1846) p. 171

Other examples of this kind of mismatch may arise with the perhaps badly named "singular they" as in:

> any student **has** as much time as they **want** to take to complete the test.

*[Kill the Messenger: The War on Standardized Testing](https://books.google.com/books?id=05VjFXLxH-IC&pg=PA51&dq=%22any%20student%20has%20as%20much%22%20%22as%20they%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjbgZff57HTAhVl2oMKHVUxAyAQ6AEIJDAA#v=onepage&q=%22any%20student%20has%20as%20much%22%20%22as%20they%22&f=false),* by Richard P. Phelps

Other relevant posts:

- [subject-verb agreement for singular they](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/226824/subject-verb-agreement-for-singular-they)
- [Why isn’t singular ‘they’ used with 3Sg verb forms?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/207502/why-isn-t-singular-they-used-with-3sg-verb-forms)
- [Why do we say "You are" when you is singular instead of "You is"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/200673/why-do-we-say-you-are-when-you-is-singular-instead-of-you-is)
- [Historical usage of "was"/"were" with "you"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22429/historical-usage-of-was-were-with-you)

Comment: The so-called *singular they* is normally used to keep the gender neutrality. The collective nouns can take either singular or plural verbs as well as singular or plural pronouns as per the intention of the writer/speaker, but there should be a consistency through out the sentence to make it idiomatic.

Comment: @mahmudkoya: can you cite a source? That just sounds like a rule that someone would come up with out of a desire to make things neat and orderly. As I said, some might find "China has as much claim to North Korea as they have over Tibet" to be bad style, but I don't see how it is not "idiomatic."

Comment: The sentence *Your Highness is as generous as you are eloquent* has grammatically  two different subjects (though they imply one person with an imbalanced use of *Highness*). If it is rephrased as *Your Highness is as generous as your Highness is eloquent* or *You are as generous as you are eloquent*, also the subjects and verbs agree correctly and the sentences become idiomatic. In the sentence *any student has as much time as they want to take to complete the test* **they** is used to keep the gender neutrality.

Comment: @mahmudkoya: so you're saying that "Your Highness is as generous as you are eloquent" is not idiomatic as it is? What do you mean exactly by "idiomatic"? I generally understand that word to refer to things that sound natural to native speakers.

Comment: @mahmudkoya: No, not particularly. I am told that some native speakers of languages like Spanish find the "singular they" odd but it sounds normal to me, and all of the examples in my answer sound natural to me. The "Your highness is... you are" example also sounds normal to me (at least, as normal as any sentence with "your highness" is going to be).

Comment: Don't you feel anything unnatural when the same person or thing denoted by the subject or object is treated differently one time as singular and other time as plural in a sentence?

Comment: @mahmud koya: Nothing unnatural about it at all in AmE. *"After the game is over, the team goes to their homes"* is much, much better than *"After the game is over, the team goes to its homes."* (Although in England, you'd say *"the team go to their homes"*.)