# Is a plural pronoun OK when it refers back to a singular institution or entity?

Tags: grammatical-number

Is a plural personal pronoun OK when it refers back to a (singular) institution or entity?  E.g.,

> **The bank is** uncooperative; **they** just **don't** answer.

Or:

> **Facebook doesn't** care about fake news; **they** just **pretend** to police it.

Comment: Related: [Are collective nouns always plural, or are certain ones singular?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1338), [How to resolve mixing singular and plural on the same noun](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/385362)

Comment: Thanks for your edit, sumelic.  It made my question clearer.  Buffalo Bill