# Singular you - "you was" or "you were"?

Tags: grammar

Lately I stumbled across a sentence where one person was talking to another person and used

> But you was thinking about it!

I'v always used "But you **were** ..." in this case and assumed that it just was a mistake or a joke I didn't get (as a non-native speaker). However, I stumbled across a similar case again today! Were I living a lie?

---

An earlier question on EL&U, [Historical usage of "was"/"were" with "you"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22429/historical-usage-of-was-were-with-you), asks about this usage during the American Civil War, whereas the current question is about *contemporary* usage. However, [Peter Shor's answer to that question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22429/historical-usage-of-was-were-with-you/22502?s=1%7C0.3089#22502) mentions contemporary usage.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Historical usage of "was"/"were" with "you"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22429/historical-usage-of-was-were-with-you)

Comment: Yeah, Peter Shor's answer was a part of why I voted to close as duplicate. Do you want a more in-depth answer than that?

Comment: From Peter Schor's answer: "..... you was became heavily stigmatized by the end of the nineteenth century in America (though it has by no means dropped out of colloquial speech in the United States)."   I would never say "you was" except maybe in a joke (you wuz robbed!), and if you are a non-native speaker, I recommend that you avoid it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to answer this without context. Using "was" (when "were" would be the correct form) may be locally idiomatic, or ironic, or stylistic, or just poor English.

For example, a common idiomatic usage is:

> **[We wuz robbed!](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/we-wuz-robbed)**
>   Also, **we was robbed** or **we were robbed**. We were cheated out 
>   of a victory; we were tricked or outsmarted. For example,
>   *That ball was inside the lines—we wuz robbed!* This expression, with
>   its attempt to render nonstandard speech, has been attributed to fight
>   manager Joe Jacobs (1896–1940), who uttered it on June 21, 1932, after
>   his client, Max Schmeling, had clearly out-boxed Jack Sharkey, only to
>   have the heavy-weight title awarded to Sharkey. It is still used, most
>   often in a sports context.

Comment: So, it is actually correct to say "You were thinking ... "?

Comment: Yes! "You was thinking" is not standard English.