# Why is "you was" used in these song lyrics?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, lyrics, be, conjugation

I was listening to a piece of music from Joan Jett called "I hate myself for loving you" and she sang:

> "Hey, man, bet you can treat me right.
>   You just don't know what you was missin' last night."

Why "you was"? It supposed to be "you were"?

Comment: Song lyrics tend not to be good examples of proper grammar. Your supposition is probably correct.

Comment: Related: [Singular you - “you was” or “you were”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/340914)

Comment: It is not "supposed to be" *you were*. It is what is: *you was*, which is considered "non-standard"  by the people who decide what the "standard" is.

Comment: Because song lyrics are written by illiterates.

Comment: @Ricky Whether or not that's true, it's probably not the reason here. These lyrics are clearly written in a dialect that uses this conjugation regularly.

Comment: It's a song lyric, and apparently one that attempts to mimic the speech of "uncultured" individuals.  As a general rule, song lyrics are off-topic here.

Comment: It's a song lyric.  As a general rule, song lyrics are off-topic here, as Hot Licks says. Brian May, I think it was, when asked about the meaning of the lyrics of 'Bohemian Rhapsody', responded 'What meaning?' (OWTTE).

Comment: Hickspeak. Or maybe a white person's attempt at AAVE.

Comment: @curious-proofreader - Or maybe an attempt at Mayberry-speak.

Answer (score 1):

The Financial Times has an [article](http://www.ft.com/cms/s/0/49711570-5a0d-11de-b687-00144feabdc0.html) with  Alan Sugar's use of "You was" on the UK's The Apprentice as its starting point. It later discusses how speakers often use

> "code-switching", changing grammatical constructions depending on the context. [...]

Hopefully it is "fair-use" to quote a short snippet of the long article:

> "It seems you was a prophet," he [Sugar] told one contestant during the final of this year's The Apprentice.  Critics have asked why the BBC, as a supposed guardian of the language, allows this sort of thing.
>   [...]
>     To some, this merely proves that poor education knows no boundaries. But in their study "Was/were variation: A perspective from London" , Jenny Cheshire and Sue Fox of Queen Mary, University of London, write that those who say "you was" have history on their side. "You was" is hundreds of years old.
>
> It has been used in many parts of the English-speaking world. "You was" appeared in Tristan da Cunha and in New Zealand in the 19th century. It is common in parts of the eastern US today, as well as in England. Older people use the construction as much as teenagers do. Sometimes older people use it more. In Birmingham, researchers found that older people were more likely than adolescents to say "you was".
>   "You was" appears, too, in the south-west of England, East Anglia and in Sir Alan's native east London.
>   - michael.skapinker@ft.com